# 'Can't find hdf5 library' while installing netCDF4

Tags: shared-libraries, hdf5, netcdf

I am trying to build NetCDF4 from source on MacOSX. When I run ./configure I get the error:

```
checking for library containing H5Fflush... no
configure: error: Can't find or link to the hdf5 library. Use --disable-netcdf-4, or     see config.log for errors.
```

I installed hdf5 before, and set the environment variables as:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include
```

In /opt/local/lib I have these files:

```
libhdf5.8.dylib             
libhdf5.a               
libhdf5.dylib               
libhdf5.settings            
libhdf5_cpp.8.dylib         
libhdf5_cpp.a               
libhdf5_cpp.dylib           
libhdf5_hl.8.dylib          
libhdf5_hl.a                
libhdf5_hl.dylib            
libhdf5_hl_cpp.8.dylib          
libhdf5_hl_cpp.a            
libhdf5_hl_cpp.dylib
```

And in /opt/local/include I have:

```
hdf5.h      hdf5_hl.h
```

Why doesn't the configure script find the hdf5 library? I am happy to provide more information if needed!

EDIT:
My ultimate goal is to install netcdf4 for use as a Fortran module. I have tried installing everything through MacPorts, and it seemed to work, but when I tried to use it, the compiler told me that there was no netcdf.mod file, and sure enough there wasn't one to be found anywhere. 
It turns out that just typing:

```
sudo port install netcdf-fortran
```

only installs the library files, but doesn't create a .mod file, which I guess is needed. So I found out that other people had the same problem, and the advice given was to install it with gcc44, which did create a .mod file, but then my compiler told me that the .mod file was built with a different version of gfortran and it couldn't be used, so that's why I am trying to build it from scratch, but if someone has a faster option, I would be more than happy to try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out. 
I reinstalled netcdf-fortran with macports, then the .mod file suddenly appeared, I then had the problem, however, that when running gfortran, it would tell me that netcdf.mod was compiled with a different version of fortran than the one I am using. (Macports uses 4.8), so got gcc48 from macports and am using gfortran-mp-4.8 to compile now and it works.

Still don't know how to build all these things from scratch, but it works now at least!!!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I see this when there is a downstream dependency that cannot be fulfilled.  The test program created by `configure` is finding `libhdf5`, but compilation is still failing because it cannot find something like `libz` or `libszip`, depending on how your libhdf5 was compiled.

If you check your `config.log` file and look for the error, it will probably tell you something along the lines of 'unresolved symbol'.  This will give a clue as to which library is missing.  If it is linking against the statically-built libhdf5, you may need to add the appropriate library using`LDFLAGS`.

If you post the relevant portion of your `config.log` file, we may be able to help sort out what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/raspstephan/c6faf797b62417f6b224) is my config.log for the hdf5 installation. [This one](https://gist.github.com/raspstephan/71e30d119ce80ab0dfbb) is for the netcdf installation, which failed.

Comment: Added a bit to my original question above, maybe helping me with that is easier...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (not finding the HDF5 libraries), and passing all arguments to configure on the same line as follows seemed to work:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/my/HDF5/include" CC=mpicc LDFLAGS=-L/my/HDF5/lib LIBS=-ldl ./configure [...]
```

Comment: I tried all above and other suggestions online but this one worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it doesn't work in the configure parameters like

```
 ./configure --enable-shared --enable-fortran --enable-netcdf-4 
 CPPFLAGS=-I$home/apps2/include LDFALGS=-L$home/apps2/lib --prefix=$home/apps2
```

or doesn't work when export `CPPFLAGS=-I$home/apps2/include` in the open SHELL.
Maybe you can set the env vars `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` in the .bashrc file (prior to the first two ways).